# Meaning symbol $\overline{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}}$

Tags: notation

I found this symbol on a math book that I'm studying. It had never happened before. What does this mean?

$$\overline{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}}$$

Comment: It's another notation for $\limsup$. `\varlimsup` produces $\varlimsup$ in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's another notation for $\limsup$. $\LaTeX$ has the command `\varlimsup` to produce it: $\varlimsup$. Similar is `\varliminf` producing $\varliminf$ for $\liminf$.